# Integrating WPF forms and normal C# forms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dynamic-data-display

For a project I decided to use Dynamic Data Display to generate charts (more specifically: heat maps) of certain data.

Now for as far as I could read (and see from the demos) Dynamic Data Display uses WPF forms.

I have no experience whatsoever with WPF, but I was wondering if it is possible to integrate Dynamic Data Display in a normal windows forms project (even if this means "mixing" Dynamic Data Display's WPF forms with my project's normal windows forms).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost` control in your Windows Forms project, more information on how to use [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) to host WPF forms inside Windows Forms is at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797.aspx (Interoperability in WPF and Winforms and vice versa)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx (Walkthrough)